# Get Cache hit ratio for specifc key pattern in Redis Elastic Cache

Tags: caching, redis, monitoring

I am using redis as a cache for my application. There are different types of entities that are cached. The naming pattern is *. For example for Department cache I am using key pattern as Dept*. Similarly for Employee cache I am using key pattern as Employee_.

I want to analze effectiveness of each cache separately like what is the Cache Hit ratio for Department Cache over a certain period. Another one would be how many keys are there in Employee Cache.

How can I fetch these stats by key pattern level instead of Redis DB as a whole.

I tried to look for commands in redis documentation, but couldn't find any